# Uploading image throw ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'we html code for the editor:

```
<div id="editor">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <p>I'm an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
</div>
```

And javascript for it.

```
if (CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.version < 9) {
    CKEDITOR.tools.enableHtml5Elements(document);
}
CKEDITOR.config.height = 150;
CKEDITOR.config.width = 'auto';
CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'en';
CKEDITOR.config.language = 'en';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage,filebrowser';
CKEDITOR.config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
function loadEditor(id) {
    if (CKEDITOR.revision === ('%RE' + 'V%') || !!CKEDITOR.plugins.get('wysiwygarea')) {
        CKEDITOR.replace(id);
    } else {
        CKEDITOR.document.getById(id).setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        CKEDITOR.inline(id);
    }
}
loadEditor('editor');
```

Can somebody give me a simple explanation how to make that i can upload image straight throw ckeditor. I've been trying over a week to do it. I downloaded plugins uploadimage, and it's dependencies plugins. No "Upload" tag appear in "Image Properties" window.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UploadImage add-on only works for dropped or pasted images. If you only want Upload tab in Image Properties, you have to set [config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserImageUploadUrl) to a script that will handle the upload:

```
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images';
```

Your `upload.php` should be like this (taken from [Integrating CKEditor with a Custom File Browser](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser), example 3):

```
<?php
// Required: anonymous function reference number as explained above.
$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;
// Optional: instance name (might be used to load a specific configuration file or anything else).
$CKEditor = $_GET['CKEditor'] ;
// Optional: might be used to provide localized messages.
$langCode = $_GET['langCode'] ;

// Check the $_FILES array and save the file. Assign the correct path to a variable ($url).
$url = '/path/to/uploaded/file.ext';
// Usually you will only assign something here if the file could not be uploaded.
$message = '';

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";
?>
```